# Looping over columns to execute actions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with data in it, the header rows are on row 5. I am trying to delete certain rows, resize certain rows, and apply filter to certain rows based on the header row (row 5) name.

I am getting

> "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined-error

on the line

```
Rows(5).AutoFilter Field:=currentColumn, Criteria:="="
```

My full code sample is:

```
Public Sub deleteCells()

Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

ActiveSheet.Columns("AQ").Delete

For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(5, currentColumn).Value


' CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP COLUMN
Select Case columnHeading
    Case "Personnel Number", "Subgroup", "Number", "Cost", "Name (repeated)", "Manager Name", "Customer Specific Status"
            ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn + 1).Delete
    Case "City"
    Rows(5).AutoFilter Field:=currentColumn, Criteria:="San Deigo"
    Case "Duties"
    Rows(5).AutoFilter Field:=currentColumn, Criteria:="=" ' TRYING TO EQUAL BLANKS
    Case Else
    Columns(currentColumn).ColumnWidth = 8 ' ALSO NOT SURE IF WILL TAKE A INT AS VALUE
    End Select
Next
'Added this line on an edit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have your data, so its difficult to know what you are doing, but I did try something similar and found that if you replace

```
Criteria:=...
```

with

```
Criteria1:=...
```

(NOTE THE 1), then it may work.

Comment: Please note that this would be more a comment than an answer. If the solution is just correcting typos, the question should be better closed according to *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**."*